# don't see navigation item in application on Xcode project

Tags: swift, xcode

I have an application that has a navigation bar 
I'm adding a cancel button with a listener in my view controller:

```
navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))
```

[image]

but when I run my app 
I don't see my cancel button on the navigation bar anymore

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

your code should work but can you make sure you did the following.
1. Put the code under the view.didLoad{} in your view controller

```
class YourViewController: UIViewController {

override func viewDidload() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(addTapped))


}
}
```

2, Make sure that you have no image covered on your screen because it can hide nav bar

Comment: no i checked it, 
do i need to actually add something else in the storyboard ? beocuse in the storyboard itself i dont have any storyboard

Comment: @ChiefMadog Is that first page when you launch the app? if not, what do you have in the previous page?